# Inkscape 0.92.2 quits trying to open old file with 90dpi scaling

Tags: inkscape

My copy of Inkscape 0.92.2 has been working fine on my Mac OS Mojave system since installation last year.  Now, today, for the first time, it pops up a dialog when I open pre-existing files

[image]

When I click "OK" the dialog window closes, and so does the image window.  (Inkscape does not quit.)  I have tried all combinations of choices in the dialog window, with the same result every time.

The Mac Console utility shows a message from Inkscape:

```
27366555: RECEIVED OUT-OF-SEQUENCE NOTIFICATION: 0 vs 2743, 513 <private>
```

There are similar messages from the `contextstored` process, whatever that is.

This does not occur with every old .svg file on my disk.  It has been weeks since I used Inkscape at all, and months since I worked with the protesting files.

Does anyone have experience with this?  Does Inkscape update itself automatically?  Inkscape's date-last-modified on my system is today, but I did not [consciously] update it.  And even so, the current downloadable version is 0.92.4 but mine is 0.92.2.  I don't want to upgrade unless I have to, as my current Inkscape continues to work for some other mission-critical needs. Thanks.

Comment: Never heard of anything similar, although I'm giving Inkscape user support almost daily for a couple years now. This did not happen with the same files before?

If that's the case, I'd try to reset the preferences as a first thing (best to only rename the file, for testing, while Inkscape is not running). If that does not help, I'd make a bug report or visit the chat.

Comment: @Moini -- Good thought.  I renamed the preferences.xml file to something else, then re-started Inkscape, but unfortunately the problem persists.  :-(

Comment: As for the updating... do you depend on any extensions? The beta2 for Inkscape 1.0 is reportedly experienced as 'infinitely better' than 0.92.4 by macOS users. The only blocker for using it rather than 0.92.4 would be if you depend on any third-party extensions (which need to be updated), and if you need some specific import formats. The problem needs to be tested with 1.0beta, anyway.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks!  I see that the beta came out in September.  I'm a little skittish -- is it possible to estimate when it may emerge from beta to become official 1.0?

Comment: Early next year? Hard to say. Depends upon the discovery of any blocking bugs. If you want to be sure that yours is fixed, better test it before a release.

Comment: Excellent point about the bug fix timing.  Thanks for all your help.  Still hoping that someone chimes in with a "This happened to me, too..."  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the problem affects images that were originally imported from a .ai file.

As a workaround I downloaded Inkscape 1.0 Beta 2 (for Mac OS) and opened the .ai file with that, then saved as .svg.  The.svg saved by 1.0B2 opens without issue in Inkscape 0.92 on Mac OS.

So, the disease remains undiagnosed, but the symptoms can be treated and eradicated.  :-)